# Back button and Forward button to change date in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-calendar

In my application i have a text view to set the current date and two buttons for next date and previous date.

When click on next button i need to set the next date to text view without opening the date picker and similarly to previous button also.

Please can any one help me.

Comment: Show some relevant code please

Comment: @NanaBanana If you are ok with my answer please upvote.

Comment: @ziselos Ah-your code works to some degree of what I'm looking for. Thank you. The problem i'm having is with the "Timber" in your fun Long.toDateString

Comment: @NanaBanana what is the problem with Timber? Timber is an android library for logging (https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber). If you do not want to add Timber in your gradle you can use Log instead, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have in your layout like a textview for current date and 2 buttons, previousDateButton and nextDateButton you can make something like this:

```
    class DemoActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDemoBinding
    private var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDemoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUI()
    }

    private fun setUI() {
        binding.currentDateTextView.text = System.currentTimeMillis().toDateString("dd/MM/yyyy")

        binding.previousDateButton.setOnClickListener {
            this.calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)
            binding.currentDateTextView.text = this.calendar.timeInMillis.toDateString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        }

        binding.nextDateButton.setOnClickListener {
            this.calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            binding.currentDateTextView.text = this.calendar.timeInMillis.toDateString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        }
    }
}
```

Where toDateString is an extension function for converting long to date format (in this example i use dd//MM//yyyy). You can use whatever you like.

In my example toDateString is:

```
fun Long.toDateString(dateFormat: String): String {
return try {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    val date = Date()
    date.time = this
    formatter.format(date)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.d(
        e,
        "String.toDateString > Exception trying to parse timestamp: $this using date format $dateFormat"
    )
    ""
}
```

}